# std::ofstream does not show error when permission denied C++

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

The following code when path = "c:\" doesn't write to file c:\err.txt because permission is denied. But it doesn't generate an error at the same time. Rather, it outputs "OK".

How I can check whether the permissions would allow the write?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool writeLineToErr(string path, string err_line){
  std::ofstream outfile(path+"err.txt", std::ios_base::app);

  if(!outfile){
      cout<<"Error 1 "+path+"err.txt"+" can't open file!";
      return false;
  }

  if(outfile.fail()){
       cout<<"Error 2 "+path+"err.txt"+" can't open file!";
      return false;
  }
  outfile << err_line << endl;

  cout<<"OK";
  outfile.close();
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    writeLineToErr("c:\\","Some Line");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.

Comment: @john-murray Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example  - Done!

Comment: "How I can check whether the permissions would allow the write" - `stat()` or `access()` would be two ways.. but it can still fail (TOCTOU).

Comment: Note: [TOCTOU is not cuckoo for Cocoa Puffs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)

Comment: I notice that when I run your code on my Linux box (using `/` instead of `c:\\`), it functions the way you're expecting (fails with "Error 1"). This makes me wonder whether your problem is more Windows-related than C++-related.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Per [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) `failbit` is set if it can't open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your code works and the write operation is actually done, but for the sake of it, add a check after the write too:

```
outfile << err_line << endl;
if(outfile.fail()) cout << "Error3\n";
else cout<<"OK";
```

On my system, I'll get your `Error 1 ... can't open file` if the file isn't opened for writing successfully.

*Edit:* Or are you running Windows with `Compatibility Files` virtualization still active? If so, the file will probably be in the *Virtual Store*, not in the real `C:\err.txt` path.

Example: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`

If you find it there, you may find a lot of other stuff in there too. At least I did years ago when I had a similar problem. I decided to manually move (with admin rights) the few important files that some of my older programs had put there and then turn Virtual Store off. I can't find a good and simple official Microsoft link for how to **turn off file and registry virtualization** right now so perhaps this will do:

RegEdit:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\`
Create a `DWORD` Key with the name `EnableVirtualization` and give it the value `0`. If the key is already there, but set to something else than zero, change it.

There's more here:
[UAC Group Policy Settings and Registry Key Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd835564(v=ws.10)#BKMK_Virtualize)

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing at all. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewE You are welcome! This "feature" had me fooled for quite some time before I found out about it myself. :-)