# CopyFile cant found the file while i can open it from fopen

Tags: c++, windows, file-copying

I try to create a program that creates a backup of a folder. The problem is that when I try to use CopyFile function I get error 2 (FILE_NOT_FOUND) but I can open the file using the fopen and the exact same path. I also use utf-8 format.

```
void Folder::copy_files(std::string destination) {

    bool error = false;
    std::string destinationpath = destination;
    for (std::string i : Get_files_paths()) {
        std::string destinationpath = destination;
        destinationpath.append(split_file_folder_name(i));


#ifdef DEBUG
        char str[100];
        const char* floc_cstr = i.c_str();
        LPCTSTR floc = (LPCTSTR)floc_cstr;
        printf("\t[DEBUG]FILE_LOC_PATH: %s\n", floc_cstr);
        std::cout << "\t[DEBUG]memory loc" << floc << std::endl;
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
        FILE* fp = fopen(floc_cstr, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("file not found");
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            printf("file found \n");
            fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
            printf("%s", str);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        print_last_error(GetLastError());
#endif
        error = CopyFile(floc , (LPCTSTR)destinationpath.c_str(), false);
        if (error == false) {
            print_last_error(GetLastError());
        }
    }

}
```

From this code, I should expect to copy the file but I get the FILE_NOT_FOUND.
does anybody know why this is happening? (if you need any other part of the code let me know)

Comment: Check whether the destination path exists. CopyFile won't create folder or subfolders.

Comment: The destination path exists. Also if the destination path doesn't exist the error number is 3 (PATH_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: Can you see the file using Explorer?

Comment: Print floc just before CopyFile and check the path.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes and I can also open it with fopen and get its content

Comment: @NikosIssaris Ok, just checking. Windows has a _Compatibility Files/VirtualStore_ layer that, when active, can mess things up so that you can open files from a program using a certain path, but it'll be invisible to other programs since the real path is hidden: [Compatibility Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526601/stdofstream-dont-show-error-on-permission-denied-c/53527576#53527576).

Comment: @TedLyngmo virtual store is almost empty. even when the program runs.

Comment: The casting from `const char*` to `LPCTSTR`  makes me suspect that your `LPCTSTR` is really a `const wchar_t*`. Try using this and see what happens:
`CopyFileA(floc_cstr, destinationpath.c_str(), false);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo this change works for the files which their names are from English characters but doesn't work for the other files (Greek characters)

Comment: Is your file path unicode or multibyte?

Comment: @NikosIssaris Ah... Ok, then you should probably use `std::wstring`s instead in your project. Also, take a look at `std::filesystem::file_copy` with takes `std::filesystem::path` arguments which should work as-is with `L"paths"` and plain `"paths"`.

Comment: @Nina yes it contains English and Greek characters, at the start of the program I have ```std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8"); std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));```

Comment: @NikosIssaris Then use CopyFileW and std::wstring. You might still be able to use std::string but you should definitely use CopyFileW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help at the comments, the solution was to use `std::filesystem::copy_file(i,destinationpath);` instead  of
`CopyFile(floc , (LPCTSTR)destinationpath.c_str(), false);`
Use of *wstring* wasnt necessary. So the code now is like that:

```
void Folder::copy_files(std::string destination) {
    const char* floc_cstr = NULL;
    bool error = false;
    std::string destinationpath;
    for (std::string i : Get_files_paths()) {
        try {
            destinationpath = destination;
            destinationpath.append(split_file_folder_name(i));
            error = fs::copy_file(i, destinationpath);
            if (error == false) {
                print_last_error(GetLastError());
            }
        }
        catch(std::exception e) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "[DEBUG]" << e.what() <<std::endl;
#endif
            std::cout << "file exist\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great that it worked out. Note that `<filesystem>` has a lot of neat functions. I'm not sure what `split_file_folder_name` in your code does but it may already exist in one way or another in [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path)